# Swift - Image not coming out round

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image

My image is not coming out as a circle for some reason. What I did is defining the corner radius as half of the image width. Does this have to do something with the constraints I set for the image?

Image circle code:

```
 profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage.layer.frame.width / 2
    profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
    profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
    profileImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

What it looks like on storyboard:

[image]

What it looks like on iPhone:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

swift 4:

```
@IBOutlet weak var photoImage: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    photoImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
    photoImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
    photoImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    photoImage.layer.cornerRadius = photoImage.frame.height/2
    photoImage.clipsToBounds = true
}
```